# ASP.NET Core Identity at Register page, register then wait 5 minutes and more

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

ASP.NET Core Identity at Register page, register then wait 5 minutes and more

I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` version 5.0.0-preview.7 , .NET Core 5.0-preview , Visual Studio 2019 preview community edition, Blazor server-side.

[image]

[image]

I check database, something written to database

[image]
After press submit, I wait 10 minutes at this screen. (and still wait more, no error at dotnet console screen).

What is wrong?

Comment: It should have taken you to a Confirm(ByEmail) page. You scaffolded a lot of Identity pages, it's not clear what changes you have made.

Comment: Registration code that accept the request and execute repository action and return response to UI will be great help to see why it's happening.

Comment: I think you get downvotes for too many pictures and too little code. The relevant parts here are ConfigureServices and all changes you made.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , I scaffoled all things, even, I don't change anything (brand-new), I tend to edit these pages later, but at now, nothing change with default pages.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , I don't add more any code. This is ASP.NET Core Identity 5.0-preview, I think it is nothing different with version 3.0 so much.

Comment: Did I have error with send mail process? Where to find send mail process? How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP.NET Core Identity at Register page, register then wait 5 minutes and more

If you implement and use [custom EmailSender service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#implement-iemailsender) to send email notification to register user, which would cause above issue once EmailSender service takes long time to send email.

To troubleshoot the issue and determine if something wrong with send mail process, you can try to write some custom log to trace the execution time of key code snippet, like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    //custom log 1
    _logger.LogInformation($"Reached Into Register Method - {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");

    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

            //custom log 2
            _logger.LogInformation($"Created New User - {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");

            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
            var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                pageHandler: null,
                values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                protocol: Request.Scheme);

            //custom log 3
            _logger.LogInformation($"Generated Email Token - {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");

            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            //custom log 4
            _logger.LogInformation($"Sent Email - {DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()}");

            if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
            { 
               //...
```

In my test, if my custom EmailSender service takes about 2 minutes to send registration notification, browser user has to wait a long time for this operation.

*Logs of user registration*

[image]

*In browser Network tab, it take about 2 minutes*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will try, then feedback. Your solution may be is what I am looking for.